# how could i make this keypad have a random code every time you join? (roblox studio/lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

this is what i have right now and i have no clue how to even make random stuff (other than math.random, which doesn't work) can someone help with this please? i've been trying different things for hours and can figure out how to do any randomize codes

```
Code = "1234" 
Input = ""


function Clear()
print("Cleared")
Input = ""
end

script.Parent.Clear.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(Clear)




function Enter()
if Input == Code then
print("Entered")
Input = ""


return end
Input = ""
print("Wrong Code")
end




script.Parent.Enter.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(Enter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(to preface, i dont know anything about roblox specifically, just lua in general)
math.random is the thing to use, but it requires some specific for your case.

presuming that you need a 4-digit integer code, `math.random(1,9999)` should give that (http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial). Then, to compare it with the input (which i see is a string), you can either turn the input to a number `(tonumber("1234"))`, or the actual code to a string `(tostring(math.random(1,9999))`.

Since lua does not care for floats/integers/etc, just numbers, I would go with the tonumber route, since you dodge string formatting that way.

To seed your randomiser, you can use math.randomseed(), for example with the system time (since the seed will be different every time, the code will be different every time). note that that sets the seed for any random call after that, not just that one call.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Do you know if I could make it load on to a sign or something?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean with "load on to a sign". you can generate negative intigers if that is what you mean.
You can re-call `Code = math.random(1,9999)` whenever you want (in any function/method) to get a new code, since from your code example it seems to be a global variable.
If you mean re-seed your generator, that is possible, but i am guessing not neccesary. As a test, you can set the seed once and then generate a few codes in a row (without setting the seed againn), they should all be different.

Comment: What I mean by put it on a sign is to put it in a text label.

Comment: Ah, like that. Like i said in my original awnser, i know lua, but nothing about roblox. So for that specific question i would not know how you would go about that.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry about using Python here to show the idea. It's quite probable the mechanism is the same.

If I want `random.random()` (or other random functions in Python) to generate random codes from the beginning, I have to run `random.seed()` before `random()`.

`seed()` initializes the random generator from the system clock (or a dedicated random generator).

```
import random as r

def main(args):
    r.seed()
    print(r.random())
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: This question is tagged 'lua'